# Execute shell script after successful connection with server

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, kali-linux

create a server on port 790. This should be a listening port in continuous mode which runs something which tell you how many files can be found in /root. When you are counting you should ignore hidden files.
Here is I have done

1. I have created file at /root/script1 file which consists of the counts of the files in root
2. Created 'scr.sh'

   `#!/bin/bash
   ls | wc -l > /root/counts`
3. creating the server 
   `netcat -l 127.0.0.1 -p 790 -e 'cat /root/script1' --continuous`
4. connecting with the server
   `netcat 127.0.0.1 790`

How do I call scr.sh file while connecting with the server so that after every successful connection the script1 file updated which holds the count of the files at /root directory?

Comment: Call your scr.sh script instead of 'cat /root/script1'.  Have you scr.sh output `ls | wc -l`

Comment: @RedCricket should I echo 'ls | wc -l' in scr.sh?

Comment: yes. that's what I meant ;)

Comment: I have done like `result = $(ls | wc -l)` and then echo "$result" but getting no output

Comment: This is a question posed on the Kali tutorial http://linuxzoo.net/page/kali_wk1c.html

Comment: I had solved this by `netcat -l 127.0.0.1 -p 790 -e 'ls /root | wc -l' --continuous`